# Gulp not working on M1 MacBook Pro with OS Monterey

Tags: macos, npm, gulp, nvm

so I am trying to get gulp to run on my M1 MacBook Pro with little success so far.

I have tried a whole bunch of things from deleting the package.json to trying to install with sudo but everything gives me this error.

gulp error message:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node Sass with apple m1, Big Sur and arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095626/node-sass-with-apple-m1-big-sur-and-arm64)

Comment: @connexo I have already tried everything in that post and nothing worked :(

Comment: If you eradicate sass from the gulp equation, does gulp still not work?

Comment: @connexo why would I want to do that?

Comment: Because I don't think gulp has any problem on M1, and that is what your question claims. Narrow down your problem to ask a more precise question.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your error messages and other textual content as **text** rather than as a screen shot?  It's preferred not to use images for this purpose here, see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812) for why.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

**The solution was to change the architecture of my shell from arm64 to x86.**

Macs with M1 chip

*January 2021: there are no pre-compiled NodeJS binaries for versions prior to 15.x for Apple's new M1 chip (arm64 architecture).*

Some issues you may encounter:

1. using nvm to install, say, v14.15.4:

- the C code compiles successfully
- but crashes with an out of memory error when used
- increasing the memory available to node still produces the out of memory errors: `$ NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" ./node_modules/.bin/your_node_package`

2. when using nvm to install some versions, the compilation fails

One solution to this issue is to change the architecture of your shell from arm64 to x86.

Let's assume that:

- you already have versions 12.20.1 and 14.15.4 installed using nvm
- the current version in use is 14.15.4
- you are using the zsh shell
- you have Rosetta 2 installed (macOS prompts you to install Rosetta 2 the first time you open a Intel-only non-command-line application, or you may install Rosetta 2 from the command line with softwareupdate --install-rosetta)

```
//# Check what version you're running:
$ node --version
v14.15.4
//# Check architecture of the `node` binary:
$ node -p process.arch
arm64
//# This confirms that the arch is for the M1 chip, which is causing the problems.
//# So we need to uninstall it.
//# We can't uninstall the version we are currently using, so switch to another version:
$ nvm install v12.20.1
//# Now uninstall the version we want to replace:
$ nvm uninstall v14.15.4
//# Launch a new zsh process under the 64-bit X86 architecture:
$ arch -x86_64 zsh
//# Install node using nvm. This should download the precompiled x64 binary:
$ nvm install v14.15.4
//# Now check that the architecture is correct:
$ node -p process.arch
x64
//# It is now safe to return to the arm64 zsh process:
$ exit
//# We're back to a native shell:
$ arch
arm64
//# And the new version is now available to use:
$ nvm use v14.15.4
Now using node v14.15.4 (npm v6.14.10)
```

*source: [Failed to "nvm install 8.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104335/failed-to-nvm-install-8-0-0/68106111#68106111)
*source: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm*